# Why is this code not working in Joomla 1.5, but the equivalent is?

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla1.5

In Joomla 1.5, why is it that the following code doesn't generate any 
results:

```
$db->setQuery($qry);
$values = array();
if ($cur = $db->query())
{
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($cur)) $values[] = $row[0];
     mysql_free_result($cur);
}
```

whereas the following does (with the same query):

```
         $db->setQuery($qry);
         $values = $db->loadResultArray();
```

when the implementation of 'loadResultArray' uses the following logic 
which as far as I can tell is the same as the first code sample above?

```
public function loadResultArray($numinarray = 0)
{
     if (!($cur = $this->query())) {
         return null;
     }
     $array = array();
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_row( $cur )) {
         $array[] = $row[$numinarray];
     }
     mysql_free_result( $cur );
     return $array;
}
```

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but you might want to upgrade to at least Joomla! 2.5, which is still being updated with security fixes. Joomla! 1.5 was abandoned a long time ago.